# Using parameters in a code behind vb.net file on a DataSource to prevent injection attacks

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parameters

We would like to change the following coding so it will use parameters to prevent injection attacks.

Here is the code in the Public Class area:

```
Public Class Parents1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim theTableAdapter As New DataSetParentsSummaryTableAdapters.ParentsSummaryTableAdapter
```

Here is what we have in the page_load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    GridViewParentsSummary.DataSource = theTableAdapter.GetData("ALL")
End Sub
```

Here is the code used to load a GridView with data from a Search button click:

```
Protected Sub ButtonSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSearch.Click

    GridViewParentsSummary.DataSource = theTableAdapter.GetData(TextBoxSearch.Text)
End Sub
```

Can you show the needed code required to use parameters?

Comment: there are no parameters here. do you have sql command somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to replace TexBoxSearch in theTableAdapter.GetData(TextBoxSearch.Text) with the parameter. Can you show me what coding to make the parameters that are needed?

Comment: What does the code for theTableAdapter.GetData look like?  From the small code snippet above, that would be the place to use the parameterized SQL query.

Comment: For the code, I'm not sure because I dragged a table from the Data Explorer onto the DataSet designer surface so the designer did that for me.